# not able to 301 redirect url in drupal

Tags: drupal, .htaccess, http-status-code-301

i am trying to redirect an url from location a to b using .htaccess with the following code

```
RewriteRule ^accessibility$ http://example.com/topic/accessibility/ [R=301,L]
```

it is not working

i have this turned on

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Are you sure mod_rewrite is properly working?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're right: that won't work. Use the [Path redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/path_redirect) module instead. Here is an excerpt from its project page:

> ... allows you to specify a redirect from one path to another path or an external URL, using any [HTTP redirect status](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/accessibility$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/topic/$1 [L,R=301]
```

BTW, `mod_rewrite` related questions are better asked on [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/), so don't be surprised if a moderator migrates this question over there.